# Is it possible to invoke Update command of a grid programatically outside the grid?

Tags: asp.net, gridview, webforms

I have a GridView with an Edit button that opens a record for editing with the Update command.  This is wired up to the RowEditing event in the codebehind and works as expected when clicked.

However, I am hacking my GridView to support inserts.  This involves adding a blank entity to the beginning of my entity collection before assinging the collection to the datasource and then opening the first row for edit.  It looks like this:

```
MyDataGrid.DataSource = New MyEntity() {New MyEntity()}.Union(MyDbEntities)
MyDataGrid.EditIndex = 0
MyDataGrid.DataBind()
```

It works and opens up a blank row where a brand new record can be added.  However, it doesn't trigger the RowEditing event.  I need to trigger this event because some special code is executed to prepare specific controls before they are delivered to the client.  I know that I could create a helper method that accepts a GridViewRow object as a parameter, but I'd really like to invoke the grid's Update command on a particular row so that everything flows naturally.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sub-classing the GridView, or just wrapping it in a lot of extra code?

If you are subclassing, you should have access to the `OnRowEditing` protected method.  If you call that, it will fire the event (assuming an event handler is attached to it.)

I would recommend subclassing, actually - it will result in something more portable and reusable, and you'll be able to access quite a few methods that you otherwise won't be able to.

Comment: I am not subclassing.  I never have, actually, and looking into it appears to be good deal of code work to have access to protected members from outside the class.  I'll probably just create a helper method and pass the row object to it.